# Error MT2001: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Error while processing references

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm getting this error trying to build a Xamarin.iOS project referencing a .NET Standard 2.0 library.

None of the MT2001 issues online seem to have this specific "Error while processing references" reason, so I'm at a loss as to how to diagnose this. I've tweaked and fiddled about as much as any one person can and stay sane, but I'm really in the dark.

Can anyone out there point me in a direction?

Comment: This kind of error often refers to some unconventional file's name, broken reference or even an invalid property value on the target platform. Maybe sharing your output can give us an idea of where we can point you to go through.

Comment: I've been having this issue recently trying to link a custom fork of OpenTK.  Since there's a namespace conflict with Xamarin's old old old fork, I had to rename all of OpenTK.  I'm also having issues getting GLES bindings to actually work, but that's another problem.  I'll contribute some more info when I can.

Comment: I ended up having to revert to a previous commit that worked and now I'm slowly working my way forward again, prodding the soil nervously with my landmine stick, waiting for something to explode.

Comment: Anyone find a solution to this? I'm having this issue and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6):

Adding `-v -v -v -v` to "Additional mtouch arguments" in the project iOS Build settings will help diagnose the issue. After that, you can search the build output for MT2001 and view the inner exceptions. Obviously, each project may differ as to what assembly causes the linker to fail. You may need to add, remove or fix your references based on the output.

For example, I was trying to use SignalR from AspNetCore 2.1, which has a dependency on `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` 4.5.1 in my project, which it seems [Mono does not yet support](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4629). Mono does not provide its own version of the assembly yet, so when mtouch goes to link the assembly, it's unable to do so and throws an exception:

```
Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
```

Removing all references to this assembly (and therefore the whole feauture in my case) allowed the build and linking to succeed.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Turns out, I had included a nuget package in my (.Net Standard 2.0, but might not be relevant) Core library, but forgot to include it in my platform specific project.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I get this when using a Xamarin library that is dependent on System.Reactive 4.1.0. There's a bug in there associated with System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, and since it is a library I'm writing, I had to roll back to System.Reactive 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error is as follows.
one of the package is mentioned in package.config file but it was not available in packages. So i added the missing package from nuget and the app works fine