# Xamarin-IOS build error - Could not link assemblies. Error while processing reference of the project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've found very strange problem in our project.
We at office are working from different MAC computers, on same project.

I have build error on my project but my workmate doesn't.

This is the error I have

[image]

And full **Build Output** is this

```
 Module: EuroProduct.SharedPCL.dll

    No compiled resources. Skipping writing assembly.
Target _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
    Touching "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/obj/Debug/netstandard2.0/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj.CopyComplete".
Target GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj" is building "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.TransferModels/EuroProduct.TransferModels.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj" is building "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/SharedAbstractions/SharedAbstractions.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):

Target GenerateBuildDependencyFile:
  Skipping target "GenerateBuildDependencyFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    EuroProduct.SharedPCL -> /Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.dll

Done building project "EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj".
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/EuroProduct.IOS.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target _BeforeCoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileInterfaceDefinitions" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _BeforeCoreCompileImageAssets:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCoreCompileImageAssets" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreCompileImageAssets:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileImageAssets" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreCompileColladaAssets:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileColladaAssets" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCoreCompileSceneKitAssets" because it has no inputs.
Target _CoreCompileSceneKitAssets:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileSceneKitAssets" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCompileTextureAtlases:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCompileTextureAtlases" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCompileTextureAtlases:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCompileTextureAtlases" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCompileTextureAtlases:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCompileTextureAtlases" because it has no inputs.
Target _CoreCompileTextureAtlases:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileTextureAtlases" because it has no inputs.
Target _BeforeCompileCoreMLModels:
  Skipping target "_BeforeCompileCoreMLModels" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreCompileCoreMLModels:
  Skipping target "_CoreCompileCoreMLModels" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreOptimizePngImages:
  Skipping target "_CoreOptimizePngImages" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CoreOptimizePropertyLists:
  Skipping target "_CoreOptimizePropertyLists" because it has no inputs.
Target _CoreOptimizeLocalizationFiles:
  Skipping target "_CoreOptimizeLocalizationFiles" because it has no inputs.
Target _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/EuroProduct.IOS.csproj" is building "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/EuroProduct.IOS.csproj" is building "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/SharedAbstractions/SharedAbstractions.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):

Target ResolveProjectReferences:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/EuroProduct.IOS.csproj" is building "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/EuroProduct.IOS.csproj" is building "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/SharedAbstractions/SharedAbstractions.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/EuroProduct.IOS.csproj" is building "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/EuroProduct.IOS.csproj" is building "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/SharedAbstractions/SharedAbstractions.csproj" (GetNativeManifest target(s)):

Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CoreCompile:
  Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
    Touching "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/EuroProduct.IOS.csproj.CopyComplete".
Target GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/EuroProduct.IOS.csproj" is building "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):

    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/EuroProduct.IOS.csproj" is building "/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/SharedAbstractions/SharedAbstractions.csproj" (GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target(s)):

Target CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
    EuroProduct.IOS -> /Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/EuroProduct.IOS.exe
Target _DetectSigningIdentity:
    Detected signing identity:
      Bundle Id: com.mpdc.europroduct
      App Id: com.mpdc.europroduct
Target _CopyResourcesToBundle:
  Skipping target "_CopyResourcesToBundle" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _DetectDebugNetworkConfiguration:
      DebugIPAddresses: 127.0.0.1
Target _CompileAppManifest:
  Skipping target "_CompileAppManifest" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ParseExtraMtouchArgs:
      NoSymbolStrip Output: true
      NoDSymUtil Output: false
Target _CompileToNative:
    /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.IOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/response-file.rsp 
    MTOUCH : error MT2001: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Error while processing references of 'EuroProduct.IOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "EuroProduct.IOS.csproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "EuroProduct.IOS.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Ideine.ModernHttpClient 3.2.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.10' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
/Users/tornikegomareli/Desktop/MPDCEuroProduct/EuroProduct-master/EuroProduct.SharedPCL/EuroProduct.SharedPCL.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'MPDC.Container 1.0.6' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
MTOUCH : error MT2001: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Error while processing references of 'EuroProduct.IOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
    4 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.58

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.58

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build: 1 error, 4 warnings
```

I've searched many problems like this, on stack-overflow but could not find any solution to solve my problem.

I deleted also some packages but no any help.
But when I'm deleting **Xamarin-FFImageLoading** package
it is building without any problem.
FFMImageLoader version is 2.3.6, also updated at last version but nothing helped.

Please give me advice, for what to do in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Adding -v -v -v -v to "Additional mtouch arguments" in the project iOS Build settings will help diagnose the issue. After that, you can search the build output for MT2001 and view the inner exceptions. Obviously, each project may differ as to what assembly causes the linker to fail. You may need to add, remove or fix your references based on the output.
For example, Maybe you had included a nuget package in your(.Net Standard 2.0, but might not be relevant) Core library, but forgot to include it in your platform specific project.

Here is [a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51457268/error-mt2001-could-not-link-assemblies-reason-error-while-processing-referenc) that you can refer.

In addition,what is the version of your VS?This problem sometimes appear when you update the VS.

Comment: My VS version is 7.6.8, it's happening after VS update

Comment: Try to delete the folder bin and obj.Then rebuild the project